# Using dropzone.js, I would like to send custom formData

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

In the standard implementation of DropzoneJs, formData contains both the file contents and a bunch of metadata. This makes it difficult to parse reliably at the server. This can also cause memory issues.

Ideally, formData would only contain the document data. All metadata would be contained in the headers.

Using JavaScript, how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for `FileReader`

```
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onloadend = function () { 
    console.log(fileReader.result) 
};
fileReader.readAsBinaryString(Dropzone.forElement('#[your dropzone element id here]').files[0]);
```